# How to resent the curl request if the output is empty

Tags: php, curl

How to resend curl request if the output is empty or something like (Database maintenance, please check back in 10 minutes) Want to refresh request if it is similar to any above.

Im using basic curl method

```
$this->ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    @curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.23 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)');

    // site is returning a gzipped body, force uncompressed
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
```

If this is very simple question, Im really sorry Because im new.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check curl_error and based on that  recall the curl request

Comment: How to recall the curl request ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want refresh it immediately in same script execution you can do something like that:

```
    $response = curl_exec($this->ch);

    if (empty($response)) {
        sleep(10);
        $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
    }
```

Or combination of that in some loop if you want check like 3 times or more.